# Is there a way to keep current window active when opening a new program?

Tags: window, task-management

An example:

> I Open up Chrome (first) and after; *Documents*. Chrome opens first, so I start entering a url. In the middle of writing it, *Documents* opens and becomes my new active window; so now I'm searching *Documents* for the remainder of the url.

It is **extremely** annoying, and I've noticed on Windows that doesn't happen - I get to stay on my active window while the new program I've opened is put out of 'focus'.

So my question is:  **Is there a way to keep my current window active when opening a new program, so that the newly opened program is out of 'focus'?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be exactly what you are looking for, but if you keep the window in front of all other windows, it will keep focus.

So, right click the title bar and check `Always on Top`.